# Dynamically Generate Bar Graph: JS, Jquery, CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some code that isn't completely working... Currently it generates a bar graph from an array but I can't figure out how to pass unique height values. If I pass one value for height all the bars are the same height. If I pass an array for height values it doesn't work.

I have a git repo if it helps.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="graph-wrapper">

            <script id="barGraph-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

                <div class="bar-wrapper">
                    <div class="bar"></div>
                    <div class="title">{{charCount}}</div>    
                </div>

            </script>

        </div> <!-- end graph-wrapper -->

    </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var charArray = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];
    var charValues = [10, 35, 90, 72, 50, 22, 16, 20, 10, 5, 2, 3, 1];

    var templateSource = $('#barGraph-template').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource);

    for (var key in charArray){ 
        // Bars are all the same height  
        // $('.bar').css('height','70%');

        // This sets all the bars to the same height w/the last value
        // in the array
        $('.bar').css('height', (charValues[key] + '%');

        var graph =  {
            charCount: charArray[key],
        }

        var readyTemplate = template(graph);
        $('body').append(readyTemplate);
    }      

});
```

**CSS**

```
.graph-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
}

.bar-wrapper {
    /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
    display: inline-flex;   /*Positions bars side by side*/
    flex-direction: column; /*Stacks bar and label*/
    justify-content: flex-end;  /*Grows bar from bottom*/
    align-items: center;    /*Aligns bar label and bar on center horizontally*/
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.title, .bar {

}

.bar {
    /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
    /*height: 70%;*/
    width: 30px;
    background: #00AEEF;
    bottom: 0px;
    -webkit-animation: animate-bar 1.25s 1 linear;
}

.title {

}

@-webkit-keyframes animate-bar {
    0% { height: 0%; }
}
```

Comment: $('.bar').css('height', 'value');  // This doesn't work - typo I assume? as 'value' shouldn't be in quotes. It should probably be css('height', (value + 'px') or something

Comment: Yes, but even when I take the quotes off it still doesn't work. Does each bar class have to be unique?

Comment: I'm realizing that the bar class is actually taking the last value in the array (1) as it's value so the bars don't have their own unique value.

Comment: Where you have multiple elements of the same class which you wish to treat differently with jquery use `eq()` as such: `$('.bar').eq(key).css('height', (charValues[key] + '%'));` this line was also missing a closing parenthesis. otherwise @BarbaraLaird 's answer below looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple problems going on here.  First, each bar is of class bar and this `$('.bar').css('height', 'value');` changes every element of class bar to a height of whatever `value` is.  Second, you've got extra quotes in this string: `var value = "'" + charValues[key] + '%' + "'";`.  Change it to `var value = charValues[key] + '%';`.  And third, you are attempting to access the elements before you add them to the dom.  They aren't added until this statement:

```
$('body').append(readyTemplate);
```

The following code is similar to what you have, but working. https://jsfiddle.net/8f6Lcv8e/ But, there is a much cleaner solution.

```
        <script id="barGraph-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

            <div class="bar-wrapper">
                <div class="bar bar{{charCount}}"></div>
                <div class="title">{{charCount}}</div>    
            </div>

        </script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    var charArray = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];
    var charValues = [10, 35, 90, 72, 50, 22, 16, 20, 10, 5, 2, 3, 1];

    var templateSource = $('#barGraph-template').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource);

    for (var key in charArray){
        var value = charValues[key] + '%';

        var graph =  {
            charCount: charArray[key],
        }

        var readyTemplate = template(graph);
        $('body').append(readyTemplate);

        $('.bar'+charArray[key]).css('height',value); 

    }      

});
```

Change your handlebar template to accept an array of objects

```
<script id="barGraph-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each .}}
  <div class="bar-wrapper">
    <div class="bar" style="height:{{y}}%"></div>
    <div class="title">{{x}}</div>
  </div>
  {{/each}}

</script>
```

And your javascript becomes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var graph = [{x:2,y:10},{x:3,y:35},{x:4,y:90},{x:5,y:72},{x:6,y:50},{x:7,y:22},{x:8,y:16},
    {x:9,y:20},{x:10,y:10},{x:11,y:5},{x:12,y:2},{x:13,y:3},{x:14,y:1}];

    var templateSource = $('#barGraph-template').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource);

    var readyTemplate = template(graph);
    $('body').append(readyTemplate);

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/agm9e31o/

Comment: A much more elegant and cleaner solution!

Comment: Can you tell me why  my bar-wrapper div doesn't display inside of my graph-wrapper div? You can see this on your jsfiddle link - I have a border on the graph-wrapper.

Comment: You're setting flexbox container attributes on the flexbox items.  See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for a nice write up on using flexbox

Comment: When I add a div above the bar for a 'y' label the bars animate down instead of up. I can't seem to identify what is changing the direction of animation:  https://jsfiddle.net/agm9e31o/2/